# How to prevent reload of Webview page

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, android-studio

I have created an app in which i have 3 tabs to display webpages using fragment. Every time i switch to tab 2 from tab 1 and then back to tab 1, tab 1 reloads. I have searched google and solutions which i found didn't work. So far i have tried this:

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
mWebView.saveState(outState);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState); 
}
```

And this:

```
 <activity ...
      android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true">
```

Here is my Main Activity

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.tech.slidechat.adaptor.SlidingTabLayout;
import com.tech.slidechat.adaptor.TabsPagerAdapter;

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 SlidingTabLayout tabs;
 ViewPager viewPager;
 TabsPagerAdapter adapter;

 Toolbar toolbar;

CharSequence Titles[]={ "tab1", "tab2", "tab3" };
int Numboftabs =3;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }

        @Override
        public int getDividerColor(int i) {
            return 0;
        }
    });

    tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And this is one of my Webview Fragments:

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.view.KeyEvent;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
  import android.webkit.WebView;
  import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
  import android.widget.ProgressBar;

  public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

private ProgressBar progress;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

    String url = "http://myurl.com";
    WebView myWebView  = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewGames);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new myWebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    progress = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progress.setMax(100);
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);


    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url) {
            View.loadUrl(url);
            GamesFragment.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            return true;
        }
    });


    myWebView.setOnKeyListener(new android.view.View.OnKeyListener()

    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    return rootView;

}


private class myWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        GamesFragment.this.setValue(newProgress);
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
}

public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progress.setProgress(progress);
}


}
```

One interesting thing is that whenever i use Tab1 and Tab2 non of them reloads but when i switch to Tab3 and then goes back to Tab1 then only it reloads.

Any Help would deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you tried adding:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

According to documentation, setOffscreenPageLimit is to:

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
>
> ...
>
> You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex >layouts. This setting defaults to 1.

The default is 1 so when you go to tab 3 there are two tabs the the left of the current tab so tab 1 gets recreated.